# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point In .Net MAUI Xunit

Tags: maui, xunit

I am getting **"Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"** error while run the Xunit project in .NET MAUI

```cs
public class UnitTest1
{
  [Fact]
  public void Test1()
  {
  }
}
```

Reproduce :

1. Create an MAUI application and add a new project XUnit to the solution.
2. Reference the MAUI project to the XUnit project.
3. Run the Test cases then get the above exception.

Using Visual Studio 17.3 Preview 2.0

Comment: XUnit projects are not designed to be run as console applications. The Test Explorer discovers the tests via reflection and executes them in the test framework. So "running the Xunit application" is not the way to proceed.

Comment: Addition: If you really want, you can change the XUnit project type to "console application", add a Main method that calls all your test methods, then you could also run it as a console application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make a few modifications to make xUnit work. I have a sample repository here: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauiUnitTestSample

All the modifications are in the `csproj` files of both projects and marked with a comment that starts with `xUnit`.

1. Add `net6.0` as a target in your .NET MAUI project.

```xml
<!-- xUnit: Add net6.0; here -->
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
```

2. Make the `OutputType` of the .NET MAUI project exclude the `net6.0` target

```xml
<!-- xUnit: The condition here only excludes this for the unit test project -->
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0'">Exe</OutputType>
```

3. In your xUnit project add `UseMaui` if you need to reference .NET MAUI APIs

```xml
<!-- xUnit: Add UseMaui if you need access to .NET MAUI APIs-->
<UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
```

You should now be able to add and run unit tests!

Comment: It's working with the above changes may I know the reason behind the <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net6.0'">Exe</OutputType>

Comment: I think xUnit needs a DLL to test on and when creating an actual app for the other targets it needs to be an exe. Which is strange because the exe isn't actually used, but.. Reasons I guess :D Don't forget to accept it as an answer if it helped!

Comment: As a little bit of detail, all of these should go underneath a `<PropertyGroup>` element.

Comment: Worked for me once I remembered to remove the line, <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>, which I had right after step 2 above :), if you have such a line replace it with 2.