# Unable to unit test .NET MAUI Class Library

Tags: .net, maui, xunit

I have a .NET MAUI Class Library that I am trying to Unit Test with XUnit. The Class Library targets iOS, Android and Windows.
I have created a XUnit Test project but when I try and run a test I get the following error:

```
Project targets 'net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0;net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0'
```

My .csproj file for the project I want to test has the following code:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst;net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x86;x64;ARM64;ARM32</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If I remove the line

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

I can run the unit tests but then I can't run my MAUI project on Windows.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Found a similar issue on Gihub: [Net6.0-windows(Winform project) cannot be referenced by .NETCore-App,Version=6.0(Xunit project)](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26043#issuecomment-1296831109). You may try  ALT-ENTER to open the project file of the test project and confirm if the Windows version is selected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point In .Net MAUI Xunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993478/program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-for-an-entry-point-in)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Your suggestion worked. I changed the following line in my test project from:
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
To:
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LiqunShen-MSFT I found that by changing the following line in my test project from:
net7.0
To:
net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0
it solved my problem

Comment: Glad you solved it. Remember to accept your answer, which may help others with same issue. Thanks in advance!  By the way, here is the original info from [Spydee commented](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26043#issuecomment-1296831109). Probably it could be helpful for readers.

Answer (score 1):

Go to .Net Maui project **.csproj**, replace below code

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

To

```
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net7.0'">Exe</OutputType>
```